# Convert a dataframe array item to a dataframe column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that was filled from a json response.  I can flatten the response to be a single row dataframe, but I'm struggling to determine the most efficient way to then map an dataframe object that is an array of numbers to another dataframe column.

I can make it work by using a temporary dataframe, but I'm sure there's a single line way to make this work.

```
print(dfjson['outputs.ac'])

Output:
0    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 314.1...
```

This code does what I want, but I don't like that I have to use a "temp" dataframe.

```
dftemp = dfjson.loc[:,"outputs.ac"]

df['%SolarGen']=dftemp.iloc[0]
print(df['%SolarGen'])

Output:
Name: outputs.ac, dtype: object
0       0.0
1       0.0
2       0.0
3       0.0
4       0.0

8755    0.0
8756    0.0
8757    0.0
8758    0.0
8759    0.0
Name: %SolarGen, Length: 8760, dtype: float64
```

When I use `df['%SolarGen']=dfjson.loc[:,"outputs.ac"]` it puts the array into index 0 of the %SolarGen column.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [dataframe transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I need.  I have a dataframe item that is an array I need to transpose into a dataframe column. I tried `df['%SolarGen']=pd.DataFrame(data=dfjson["outputs.ac"])` but it results in just putting the array into index 0 of the %SolarGen column as before.  Maybe you have a link to another example?  I can't seem to find one with dataframe items as arrays.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a single line solution `df['%SolarGen']=dfjson.iloc[0,30]` where 30 is the column number in the original json dataframe.  I guess the next advance is to find the column number by name so I don't have to count them or in case anything changes.

Comment: `df['%SolarGen']=dfjson.iloc[0,dfjson.columns.get_loc("outputs.ac")]` That's the advanced solution I guess.  Still learning.